# AppendChild does not work!,inheriting from DOM Element object..What Am I doing wrong here?

Tags: javascript, dom, prototypal-inheritance, appendchild

I am writing my custom elements which have some more methods than the standard DOM element,here is the one that inherits from the Element object

```
function MyObject(){

    return (Object.create(document.createElement("Mytag"),{
         myfunction:function(){
             return blahblah;
         }
    }));

}//function for creating object ends

function MyObject2(){

    return (Object.create(document.createElement("Mytag2"),{
        myfunction:function(){
            return blahblah;
        }
    }));

}//function for creating second object ends

var a=new MyObject();//statement works fine
var b=new MyObject2();//statement works fine
```

Now when i try to make one of these objects the child of the other I get any thing to work, rather an exception is being thrown

```
a.appendChild(b);
```

Comment: what exception is thrown?

Comment: and FWIW, I don't think that's an appropriate use of `Object.create`.  The add on object is supposed to contain _property descriptors_, not methods.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

Comment: Why do you want an object to inherit from a DOM element?

Comment: @Alnitak i think its a property rather than the property descriptors,i have tested working with it and the results are fine

Comment: @amnotiam I need to create my custom tags for some purpose which have their own methods and attributes along with those present in the Element.prototype itself

Comment: @user2283857: That won't create any new properties that way. Your syntax is wrong. You're saying you need to do this *(extend elements this way)*, yet you can't. You may want to, but it won't work. You'll need to find a different approach to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you use `return (Object.create(...));`, your `new MyObject();` and `new MyObject2();` return objects and not DOM elements, therefore `a.appendChild(b)` won't work, as `a` and `b` are expected to be DOM elements.

To see the difference, take a look at the console in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RWaKT/1/)

Comment: for 

    var a=new MyObject();
    typeof a;//returns an object

 and for 

    var c = document.createElement("Mytag3");
    typeof c;//still returns object

So whats the difference?

Comment: Sure, they are both `object`s, but there are many types of objects.  Inspect the console output of my updated jsFiddle to see the difference: http://jsfiddle.net/RWaKT/2/  i.e., one is a standard `object Object` (because it has been created with `Object.create`), the other one is an `object HTMLUnknownElement` (because it is a DOM Element).  The latter has the method `appendChild`, the former doesn't.

Comment: But inheritance is there?or is it not? When appendChild(e) expects e to be a node and its accepts e if it is an Element(because the Element is inherits from Node),why doesn't it accept an Object that inherits Element(as it also inherits Node because Element inherits Node)?

Comment: @user2283857: There are native JavaScript objects, and there are "host objects". Host objects are not defined in the ECMAScript specification, but rather are provided as extensions by the host environment. They don't play by all the same rules as native objects.

Comment: @user2283857: You're welcome... and yeah, it's... not optimal. But once you get your head around its quirks and limitations, the experience gets better.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass *property descriptors* to `Object.create`, not methods.

```
function MyObject() {
    return Object.create(document.createElement("Mytag"), {
        myfunction: {
            value: function() {
                 return 'blahblah';
            }
        }
    });
}
```

This does work for me in Chrome:

```
a = new MyObject();
> HTMLUnknownElement {spellcheck: true, isContentEditable: false, contentEditable:
  "inherit", children: HTMLCollection[0], outerText: ""…}
a.myfunction()
> "blahblah"
```

Note however that is has *not* correctly set the "type" of the object to `MyObject`.  Nor does it prevent an exception from being thrown when I try to add the object to the DOM :(

Comment: I passed the property descriptors before taking a step to write it directly as a method(this was just because of misunderstanding of where the error was)...but writing it directly as an attribute worked fine ,I thought we could write both of them...thanks for correction